# Octave - Why does input in a script only work once?

Tags: octave, user-input

I can't be the first one with this but searching didn't help me. This is an exercise of an edx MOOC. The first script.

```
% distance_traveled asks the user for speed and time traveled.
% It calculates and displays the distance from this.

clear all;   % a naive try, doesn't make a difference

speed = input (['Enter speed in m/s :']);

time = input (['Enter time traveled in s :']);

distance_traveled = speed * time;

disp(['Traveling for ', num2str(time), 'seconds at a speed of ', num2str(speed), 'm/s results in ', num2str(distance_traveled), ' Meters travelled.'])

>> distance_traveled
Enter speed in m/s :10
Enter time traveled in s :10
Traveling for 10seconds at a speed of 10m/s results in 100meters travelled.
>> distance_traveled
distance_traveled =  100
>> distance_traveled
distance_traveled =  100
>> distance_traveled
```

Edit: Yeah, I forgot the problem: This works only once. When I rerun the script I don't get prompted for new values, the old ones are used. 'clear all' in the command window does the trick.

I've tried adding 'clear all;' but this doesn't help.

How is this done and why is it so hard to find ?

Have a nice weekend,
Stephan

Edit2: D'oh! The answer variable in the script and the script have the same name. distance_traveled
I've changed it to just distance in the script and anything works fine.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? what is the relation between the problem and `clear all`?

Comment: When I re-run the script it doesn't prompt for new values, it just reuses the old ones. clear all in the command window before rerunning the script does the trick.

Comment: Got it: The script is called distance_traveled and it has an answer variable named distance_traveled. I've renamed this to just distance in the script and it's working fine now. How do I mark this as solved ?

Comment: Writing functions instead of scripts prevents issues like these. Calling a function doesn't add variables to your workspace.